# Problemas con PDO en Hostinger

Tags: php, pdo

¿Qué tal, alguien me podría ayudar con el siguiente problema?

Tengo una página web la cual al momento de registrarte a través de un formulario, este envía los datos a otra página para que esta cree una base de datos de el usuario (crea una base de datos, no una tabla en una base de datos con los datos del usuario). El problema es que al subirlo a Hostinger no crea la base de datos, ya he cambiado todos los datos de las conexiones, en el servidor he puesto mi servidor mysql que me proporciona hostinger así como mi nombre de usuario.

¿Alguien sabe si es posible crear bases de datos de esta manera o solo se puede directo en el phpmyadmin del Hostinger?. En el servidor local funciona de maravilla.

Aquí un ejemplo de los datos de la conexión que he cambiado.

```
$base=new PDO('mysql:host=mysql.hostinger.co; 
dbname='.$usuario,'u561307665_root','51969075');
```

la variable $usuario es el nombre de usuario recibido a través del formulario.

Comment: ¿qué paquete tienes contratado en Hostinger? Revisando la información en Hostinger.com veo que el paquete gratuito solo incluye 2 bases de datos MySQL, los paquetes con costo tienen bases de datos ilimitadas.

Comment: Estoy usando el paquete gratuito jeje, solo es para una exposición escolar así que me es suficiente con un solo usuario que se cree